# Issue with customizing grub in Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

Im facing some issues while trying to add rootdelay=60 option in grub cmdline options by editing file /etc/default/grub where

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=300"
```

---

```
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

however i do not observe any delay when the server is rebooted and the root filesystem mounts right away

i can see that the rootdelay=300 is present in cat /proc/cmdline too, any clue whats missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show the grub-menu when starting up your computer? If that is the question, then you have to use 'GRUB_TIMEOUT=60' (is time in seconds, so 60 is 1 minute ). You have to edit the file 'grub', which is located in `/etc/default`.
You have to do this as 'root', so use

sudo

in your terminal. You can use the program 'gedit' to change the file.
btw I have mine set to 10 seconds ( see screenshot ).[image]

Comment: No, its rootdelay as in https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the `rootdelay` value is how long initramfs is willing to wait, not how long it is guaranteed to wait.

The documentation you linked does seem to suggest otherwise, so here are my notes

- The initramfs `init` will take the `rootdelay` argument and create the `ROOTDELAY` variable [in this code](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/init?id=1e339db17d611774c5649720a13612010d4a6359#n111).
- The larger value between `ROOTDELAY` and 30 gets used for `slumber` [in this code](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/scripts/local?id=1e339db17d611774c5649720a13612010d4a6359#n57).
- `slumber` gets passed to the command `wait-for-root` [in this code](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/scripts/local?id=1e339db17d611774c5649720a13612010d4a6359#n73).
- `wait-for-root` appears to use the value as an exit timeout, not as a delay [in this code](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/tree/src/wait-for-root.c?id=1e339db17d611774c5649720a13612010d4a6359).

**edit**

I was looking at the [Debian source code](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/-/blob/35177dbef0ae8e9b1ea67bcb72f71f9a7b4b9934/init#L225) and there is a line `sleep "$ROOTDELAY"` that does not exist in the Ubuntu code.  I found this commit in the Ubuntu repo that deletes the line, so I'm not sure if this behavior is Ubuntu specific or even specific to certain releases.

https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/commit/init?id=07f166de18d42a434e928aea15fc674135dbf77b

> - init: Don't interpret "rootdelay" as a static sleep.

**edit 2**

I found a couple of bugs where the initramfs devs discussed removing `rootdelay` as a sleep value.  I'm still not clear when it got removed or if it only got removed in Ubuntu.

- *ROOTDELAY= causes unnecessary delay in boot* (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1615751)
- *initramfs-tools: Completely ignores rootdelay* (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=809740)